# Sharing xml string between two components on different pages in cq5

Tags: aem, sling

I tried using request attributes to share data between two jsps of two components but its not working as the second jsp is getting the new request. 
I've also gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325733/pass-data-from-one-component-to-another-in-adobe-cq) question but its not fitting my scenario.
How to share data or strings between two component jsps which are set as sling:resourceType to two different pages?
Here is more information about the scenario: There will be a link on the first component which when clicked will take to the second page having another component as a resourceType.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  It would be helpful to let us know what if anything you have tried to do to resolve this.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. Actually as a work around right now I'm writing the data to a file and reading it from another component's jsp. But checking if there is a way in CQ/Sling APIs to pass data between two JSPs/components. request.setAttribute/getAttribute does not work in this case as both pages are getting new requests.

Answer (score 0):

As you already noted, these are two different requests so attributes set on the first one would not be available on the second request, which originates on clicking the link.

I assume that the data you want to pass ( XML String ) can be pretty huge in size so you do not want to use request parameters. In that case, you could save the data in some temporary location ( in the repository or the disk ) and then pass the path to that location as a request parameter ( by encoding it in the link itself ) to the other component.